# ParserError ERC721

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I am having trouble with solving this issue.
from solidity:
ParserError: Expected '{' but got identifier
--> Mint.sol:1443:16:
|
1443 | contract Eight Founding Fathers is ERC721A, Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {
|                ^^^^^^^^

```
//below is my code//

line 1443 ignore this// 
contract Eight Founding Fathers is ERC721A, Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {

  string public        baseURI;
  uint public          price             = 0.003 ether;
  uint public          maxPerTx          = 20;
  uint public          totalFree         = 1000;
  uint public          maxSupply         = 1776;
  uint256 public       maxFreePerWallet = 3;
  bool public          mintEnabled;
  mapping(address => uint256) private _mintedFreeAmount;

  constructor() ERC721A("8Bit Founding Fathers","8BFF"){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your smart contract name shouldn't have space between words. Another issue is that missing a '}' for close `EightFoundingFathers` smart contract.
I adjusted your smart contract code in this way:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract EightFoundingFathers is ERC721A, Ownable, ReentrancyGuard {

  string public        baseURI;
  uint public          price             = 0.003 ether;
  uint public          maxPerTx          = 20;
  uint public          totalFree         = 1000;
  uint public          maxSupply         = 1776;
  uint256 public       maxFreePerWallet = 3;
  bool public          mintEnabled;
  mapping(address => uint256) private _mintedFreeAmount;

  constructor() ERC721A("8Bit Founding Fathers","8BFF"){

  }
}
```